# Closed connection socket.io android

Tags: android, angular, sockets

Recently I made some chat application.
I have just one problem which i can't fix.

So my app uses angular as client and node js with sockets as backend.
The problem is that when the client will stay idle for like 15 minutes, the phone will go to sleep mode and disconnect from server. Other user will get the message that the person left chat. But now when the person will turn phone on, he will be at the chat page causing some problems.

How can I just kick him to welcome page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect to home page, you can do it on disconnect event.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {           
     // your code goes here
});
```

[image]

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Thats on the server, but when clients phone goes off, socket connection is closed. Then when he turn on phone he want get any socket because he got disconnected.

Comment: Crap, didn't know that. Thanks!